# Remove the option to delete attachment on Edit Form

Tags: javascript, attachments

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove the "Delete" hypertext on the Edit Form whenever attachments are added. I've tried to use the JavaScript String replace() method to no luck, I've attached the code to.

[image: How could I remove the 'Delete'?]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("Delete", "");
    document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").innerHTML = res;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this piece of css:

```
.ms-delAttachments
{
 display: none;
}
```

You can open the edit form in the Advanced mode in SharePoint designer, find the `<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">` tag and include this css there. This is how it should look like after your change (tested on new form on custom list):

```
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
/* This line is added automatically so just leave it there */
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}

.ms-delAttachments
{
 display: none;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks dude - I've never edited CSS on SharePoint before how do I input this code? I'm a big newbie when it comes to SharePoint.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by more simple way,
just edit your form using browser
put one content editor
write this code in style tag
.ms-delAttachments
{
 display: none;
}
save the page.

Answer (score 0):

Below is tested and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Pages/jquery-1.9.0.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("td.ms-propertysheet:contains('Delete')").hide(); 
});
</script>
```